I want to get if any specific table is being queried inside the whole database
I want to get if any specific table is being queried inside the whole database.
Is there any way to find if any specific table is being queried inside the Database, so that I can decide what are the columns I need to add index
I got below query so far but its including delete statments as well
SELECT 
    qs.sql_handle,
    SUBSTRING(st.text, (qs.statement_start_offset / 2) + 1, 
    ((CASE qs.statement_end_offset 
      WHEN -1 THEN DATALENGTH(st.text) 
      ELSE qs.statement_end_offset 
      END - qs.statement_start_offset) / 2) + 1) AS query_text,
    qp.query_plan
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats qs
CROSS APPLY 
    sys.dm_exec_sql_text(qs.sql_handle) AS st
CROSS APPLY 
    sys.dm_exec_query_plan(qs.plan_handle) AS qp
WHERE 
    st.text LIKE '%YourTableName%'
ORDER BY 
    qs.total_worker_time DESC;

